# Hook form alter not working for node edit form

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I have a content type called `landing_page`. If I edit an existing node in the admin `/node/31/edit` and I inspect the form I see `id="node-landing-page-edit-form"`.

I can't get it to work to use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`?

I tried:

```
function MYTHEME_form_node_landing_page_edit_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_message'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => t('New article'),
    '#markup' => t('Test message'),
  );
}
```

I also tried:

```
function MYTHEME_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_message'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => t('New article'),
    '#markup' => t('Test message'),
  );
}
```

And I tried:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'node_landing_page_edit_form') {
// My code here
}
}
```

Comment: i allways use a module instead of MYTHEME and works

Comment: use MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {} and NOT MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {}, MYMODULE is called before MYTHEME

Comment: Yeah, are you adding your hooks in the right theme? So do you have a custom backend theme? If not try to add them from a custom module like pinueve suggests.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I am in the backend and have to trigger the admin theme. And indeed it's better to do it in a custom module. Then it's still working even when you change admin theme.